# What role Bob Anderson did play, Imperial or Rebel?

Tags: star-wars, casting, the-empire-strikes-back

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Anderson_(fencer)) claims that fencer and fight choreographer Bob Anderson played an Imperial Officer in *Star Wars*. This page [movie-dude.co.uk](http://movie-dude.co.uk/[Film]%20Star%20Wars%20V%20-%20The%20Empire%20Strikes%20Back%20(1980).htm) shows a Rebel Officer claiming it's Bob Anderson but the quality is so low I can't say whether it's him or not.

So whom did he play, Imperial or Rebel?

As a bonus question, is there any conclusive proof of who was wearing the costume (Anderson or Prowse) in the original Star Wars movie in the iconic fight between Vader and Kenobi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia article is mistaken. He played Trey Callum, the "the Rebel trench officer who first reports to Echo Base the sighting of AT-ATs during the opening stages of the Battle of Hoth" ([Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Trey_Callum))
[image: Bob Anderson]

As to the iconic fight scene, from an interview quoted in the question's Wikipedia article:

> Vader actor David Prowse explains that he did his own swordplay in Star Wars, but when the movie became a hit deserving of sequels, ”having one of the principals do his own stunts made (the filmmakers) very weird from an insurance point of view.”

Comment: 1) Wikipedia was wrong on whom Bob Anderson played 2) That's just David Prowse claiming something for himself. That's hardly proof.

Comment: @chx If you're looking for proof take it to Skeptics..

Comment: Thanks. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34755/did-david-prowse-do-the-lightsaber-duel-in-star-wars posted.